# Can not display Android Remote Images Titanium SDK

Tags: android, image, uiimageview, imageview, titanium

I have an image view and try to load remote image but it's can not show up.

I'm already search and try any suggestion on this forum but not work. I'm using SDK 3.2.2 on Mac OS X Maverick

My code is like here, and it's running good on iOS.

```
var iconImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    width:40,
    height:40,
    left:5,
    hires:true,
    defaultImage:'/images/default.jpg',
    image:urltoimage
});
```

[sample image](http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t567/vademahendra/sightseeing_zpsd91fa049.png?t=1401680320)

this is a bug or something wrong with my code?any suggestion how to do remote image? Please help..

Comment: What's your value hold in `urltoimage` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
exports.LoadRemoteImage = function (obj,url) {
   var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

    xhr.onload = function()
    {
     Ti.API.info('image data='+this.responseData);
     obj.image=this.responseData;

    };
    // open the client
    xhr.open('GET',url);

    // send the data
    xhr.send();
};
```

save on new file and named "ImageLoader.js"
I'm forget where I found that code, but I'm used that to handle any image from internet.

usage:

```
var ImageLoader = require('ImageLoader');
var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
width:100,
height:100
})

ImageLoader.LoadRemoteImage(imageView,"http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t567/vademahendra/sightseeing_zpsd91fa049.png?t=1401680320");
```

I hope this can help you

Answer (score 0):

I've run application with this code:

```
var urltoimage = 'http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t567/vademahendra/sightseeing_zpsd91fa049.png?t=1401680320';
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();
var iconImage = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    left: 5,
    hires: true,
    defaultImage: '/images/default.jpg',
    image: urltoimage
});
win.add(iconImage);
win.open();
```

All worked properly, so the issue has to be on your device or simulator.
Check network connection and if airplane mode is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Does it show up on the device and just not on the emulator, or does it not show up at all?

Sometimes Android can be temperamental about remote images. CDNs usually work really well which is probably why daniula's code worked.  Things to try are:

- Change the pixel dimensions of your remote image to be smaller - test
- Change the image file size of course using different compressions - test
- Try different file types
- Try using the same image url daniula used to see narrow it down to the image or the code: if the images shows up, then it's a problem with the serving of the images; if the image does not show, it may be an issue with your code.

Comment: I'm using the image from daniula which is from photobucket working fine. but from my image server not working. I think the problem is on my server.